# Saving GPS Coordinates in Contacts

Tags: ios, contacts, reminders, gps, maps

I live in a country which has few registered Apple Maps addresses.
All that i want is to store GPS coordinates in contacts to use those at the Reminders app.
I came from diverse forums like [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3828421) and [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1261335)
but it seems that there isn't a final answer to this issue.

This is what i tried so far.

- If i set an URL field with the following text `maps://=&q=35.000000,-119.000000` it seems that solves the problem since if i tap on that url it redirects me to that specific coordinate in the apple maps app. But it doesn't work at reminders since reminders looks at the address field instead of the URL one.
- So i set the coordinates at the address field then (street section) like the following `35.000000,-119.000000` which seems that solves the problem but there is a mandatory country name that breaks everything because when i tap it finds the coordinates plus the country which returns a completely different location.

Any extra help is appreciated. Is simple, all that i need is to use the Reminders app location feature with specific contacts GPS coordinates, not geocoding address ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maps://=&q= 35,-119 returns Brisbane, Australia, bizarrely. Just 35,-119 returns somewhere in California, which is correct. Test with 51.48,0.0 which should return Greenwich Royal Observatory, roughly, & confirms the data is latitude,longitude. This works when entered into an address.

Comment: Ah, I see - entering it on an iPhone messes it up, doing it on the Mac doesn't force the country & works just fine.

Comment: Yeahh, exactly, the country field breaks the search if i put the lat,long on the address, the values that show are example ones.

Comment: I use this application to erase the country. Connect

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's developer documentation about their [MapLinks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)  iOS/macOS supports map urls via a web link (using http or https) to maps.apple.com - so to link to GPS coordinates one uses:

```
https://maps.apple.com/?ll=50.894967,4.341626
```

Also just to add it seems that 'geo:' maps scheme standardised in [RFC5870](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5870) sadly doesn't appear to work on iOS/macOS. Although according to the [geouri.org](http://geouri.org/) there is some support in Android, and other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for Mac owners [I've not tested a Windows equivalent]

Add the co-ordinates in Contacts on the Mac, it doesn't insist on a Country & will then work correctly on the iPhone so long as you never edit it on the phone.

If you do, you will have to delete the address & add again from the Mac, just clearing the country from the Mac doesn't appear to reset it correctly.

Comment: As never you edit it what ?? the contact as a hole or the address ??

Comment: The address. Soon as you edit it on the phone, it puts the country back in & breaks it again.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the Notes field.  You will have to copy/paste when you want to use it but that's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Use ABGPS app :
http://roudgersoft.com/en/app/abgps/

ABGPS

• adds your GPS location to your Contacts cards.

• opens your favorite navigation app directly from the device address book.